# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo on android versions 4.+

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-play-services, runtimeexception

i'm having this error in `Android versions 4.+`, (specially in 4.1 and 4.3) while not in any other versions of android.
The Activities and libraries (i use `GooglePlayServices` and `YouTubePlayerAPI`) are referenced in Manifest.xml file and in gradle file.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.test/com.app.test.DetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.app.test.content.FirstFragment.onCreate(FirstFragment.java:151)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1763)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:913)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1912)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:266)
at com.app.test.DetailActivity.onCreate(DetailActivity.java:73)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
... 11 more
```

The code from fragment where the error is caused (line 151) is the onCreate() method of the fragment attached:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        if(getArguments() != null && getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
            // Loads the content specified by the fragment arguments.
            mItem = Items.getInstance().getMap().get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
        }

        // Initialize mCustomMediaPlayer
        mCustomMediaPlayer = new CustomMediaPlayer(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mItem.getTrackId());
    }
```

Where pointed line 151 is:

```
mCustomMediaPlayer = new CustomMediaPlayer(VillancicosActivity.getContext(), mItem.getTrackId());
```

CustomMediaPlayer Class:

```
public class CustomMediaPlayer {

    /////// Constants

    private static final String TAG = "CustomMediaPlayer";

    /////// Fields

    /**
     * The application context.
     * Is used to manage MediaPlayer and async class.
     */
    private Context mContext;

    /**
     * MediaPlayer instance.
     */
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    /**
     * The id representing track used in MediaPlayer create() method
     * where will be played.
     */
    private Integer mTrackId;

    /**
     * A flag indicating if the track is playing or not.
     */
    private Boolean mIsPlaying = false;

    /**
     * Initialize providing the application context and the calling fragment track id.
     *
     * @param context The Context to use.
     * @param trackId The raw resource id to use as datasource.
     */
    public CustomMediaPlayer(Context context, Integer trackId) {
        mContext = context;
        mTrackId = trackId;
    }

.....
}
```

This is part of the class, where the Main Constructor is called from FirstFragment in line 151.

Any idea?
Thanks everyone!

Comment: Likely `mItem` is null. `VillancicosActivity.getContext()` smells extremely bad, too.

Comment: I have tried getActivity().getApplicationContext() and gets the same error reported.

Comment: I suppose If it was in getting context, it wouldn't work in any android version and not only in 4.+

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
mCustomMediaPlayer = new CustomMediaPlayer(getActivity(), mItem.getTrackId());
```

and check `mItem ==null` or not.

Comment: I' ve tried it and mItem is null in some devices with android 2.3.3 and 2.3.7 but i don't know what causes it

Answer (score 0):

your activity does not recognize Villancicos Activity.getContext() you need to pass a valid context.
try getApplicationContext() instead.

Comment: I' ve tried getActivity().getApplicationContext() too and have the same error.

Comment: did you check if mItem!=null?